# Program a Data source (Visual Studio) alike in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I'm trying to develop a data source alike (visual studio). I have the interface all done already(easy part), but the trickies parts of this projects are:

1 - I need to populate the data source according to what the user has installed on his(her) computer, meaning that, if he doens't have Oracle, the tab won't show. -> That's the part I'm having difficult.

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

The binding part, I have a sketch, using ifs (or switchs) using the text in the data source field.

I'm using DevX in the interface !

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As there is no .NET API to get the list so you have to work with Windows registry to find the list.

[Here](http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/get-list-odbc-data-source-names-programatically-using-c) is good tutorial on finding datasource name.......

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, but the `dsnList.Add(sName, DataSourceType.System);` part is not working here, I don't know which dll I need to add to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My ODBC file is empty, so I can go trough this part of the code `reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC Data Sources");`, but in visual studio, I have a couple of odbcs installed, is it right ? Is there another way of doing this ? Thanks !

Comment: Actually, I can't go through. Sorry for the misspell.